# simpleXML and libcore.io.ErrnoException

Tags: android, simple-framework

I'm trying to create a basic Android app where an XML file is deserialized using SimpleXML. I am following this tutorial: http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#deserialize.

But I get this exception: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Here's the code for the activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView mTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        getAnimal();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void getAnimal() throws Exception{
    Serializer serializer = new Persister();
    File source = new File("animal.xml");

    Animal animal = serializer.read(Animal.class, source);
    this.mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    mTextView.setText(animal.getSpecie()); 
}
}
```

Does anyone know what causes the exception? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally solved my problem by moving the XML file to the Asset folder and replacing:

```
File source = new File("animal.xml");
```

with:

```
InputStream source = getAssets().open("animal.xml");
```